# How can I get an integer as output for continuous action space PPO reinforcement learning?

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I have a huge discrete action space, the learning stability is not good. I'd like to move to continuous action space but the only output for my task can be a positive integer (let's say in the range 0 to 999). How can I force the DNN to output a positive integer?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please specify which framework for RL agents you are using and which kind of environment?

Assuming that you are using Stable Baselines 3 (SB3) with OpenAI gym environment, you should be able to set the desired action space when you set up the environment (see here: https://www.gymlibrary.ml/content/spaces/). PPO is one of SB3's most versatile agents that can be used for "Discrete", "Box", "MultiDiscrete" and "MultiBinary" action spaces.

Lastly to get an output of a positive integer only, can be achieved in several ways:

- if your output is for example `Box(low=-1.0, high=1.0, shape=(1,)` it would be just about scaling that output to the desired range and converting it to an int.
- another option is to define your output as `Box(low=-1.0, high=1.0, shape=(N_DISCRETE_ACTIONS,)` and then get the final integer with a `np.argmax(action)`
- the direct way would be to define the action space as a `Discrete(N_DISCRETE_ACTIONS)`